# Counting the occurence of an object in a Binary Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

I am trying to develop a recursive algorithm which counts the occurrence of an object in a binary tree. Actually, I could manage to write down one but I'm not sure if it works well or is preferable if it's not, please help me fix it.

```
Algorithm count(Node, desiredObject)

counter = 0
 if(Node is empty)
    return counter
 else 
    if(Node's data is equal to the desiredObject's data)
     counter := counter + 1
 leftCounter = count(Node's left child, desiredObject)
 rightCounter = count(Node's right child, desiredObject)
 return counter + leftCounter + rightCounter
```

Comment: Your algorithm looks like it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm looks fine. Just some quick thought, it can be smaller in terms of [LOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code) and you can exclude all the counter variables.

```
Algorithm count(Node, desiredObject)

 if(Node is empty)
    return 0

 return (Node's data == desiredObject's data) + 
            count(Node's left child, desiredObject) + 
            count(Node's right child, desiredObject)
```